# How do I read from a text file into a text box?

Tags: python, textbox, stream, text-files, pygtk

I'd like to know of a way to read a text file and add its contents into a text box. I am doing this in PyGTK, so I'd need to get the text in Python, and put it into the text box using PyGTK, that would be great. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your text box is a [`TextView`](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtktextview.html):

```
#read the contents of the file
text = open("yourfile").read()
#get the underlying TextBuffer object of the TextView and set its text
textbox.get_buffer().set_text(text)
```